# Unsubscribe Collection in Google Docs Api

Tags: java, google-docs, google-docs-api

am trying to unsubscribe a shared collection but am not sure how achieve this.

i was trying to get the acl feed and the entry to delete but is not working

```
AclFeed aclFeed =entry.getAclFeed(); 
 for (AclEntry entryP : aclFeed.getEntries()) {
 entryP.Delete();
}
```

am not sure if am using the right uri to get the collection

https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/folder:12345/acl

is this right?

Comment: What errors are you seeing? What would be the expected behavior?

Comment: this is the scenario, someone share with me a folder named xyz, i want to delete this folder, but i don't own that folder, so i have to unsubscribe, how can i achieve this with the google docs api? , if i delete the AclEntry that have my mail, the folder don't go away , ¿do i have to delete the Aclentry that has like type = DOMAIN too?